# A HTML form redirects me to a login, show incorrect login message

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, forms

I have an HTML form that redirects me to aspx page with a login:

```
<form method="post" action="../login.aspx">
```

If the data is correct everything is ok, but when data fail, I need to display an error message, how I can do that?

In the aspx page I have a redirect when everything is ok, but when the login fails y try to put an alert and redirect to my html page, but this not works, the user go to the html page but the alert is not shown:

```
Response.Redirect("~/Users.aspx"); //here everything is ok
                }
            }
            // if the login is wrong
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert(the login is wrong);</script>");
                Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: The Google search you are looking for is `asp.net form validation`

Comment: This question is overly broad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the condition is wrong then please insert following code in c# code

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Your Alert Mesage Here');", true);

Comment: In the aspx page I have a redirect when everything is ok, but when the login fails y try to put an alert and redirect to my html page, but this not works, the user go to the html page but the alert is not shown:

Response.Redirect("~/Usuarios.aspx"); //here everything is ok
                }
            }
            // if the login is wrong
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert(the login is wrong);</script>");
                Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
            }

Answer (score 1):

try your script like this

```
Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('the login is wrong');</script>");
```

hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but I think you are looking for form validation in asp.net. You can easily search it from google.

But here are some handy tutorials for this. I have used recently while dealing with my form validation.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/webforms/article.php/c19353/Form-Validation.htm

http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/01/13/validation-in-asp-net-applications.aspx

You can use it.

Hope it'll help you.

Comment: In the aspx page I have a redirect when everything is ok, but when the login fails y try to put an alert and redirect to my html page, but this not works, the user go to the html page but the alert is not shown:

Response.Redirect("~/Usuarios.aspx"); //here everything is ok
                }
            }
            // if the login is wrong
            else
            {
                Response.Write("<script>alert(the login is wrong);</script>");
                Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
            }